# Index fields not supported error while migrating MongoDB data to AWS DocumentDB

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I am trying to migrate my data from **MongoDB 3.6 running on one ec2 instance** to **AWS DocumentDB running on another ec2 instance** by using **mongodump** and **mongorestore** commands.
But I am always getting at least one of following errors:

- createIndex error: Field 'default_language' is currently not
  supported
- createIndex error: Field 'language_override' is currently not
  supported
- createIndex error: Field 'weights' is currently not supported
- createIndex error: Field 'textIndexVersion' is currently not
  supported

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: Dimpal, happy to help! What type of indexes are these? DocumentDB supports single field, compound and multi key indexes - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html#mongo-apis-index.

Comment: these are text indexes with the combination of two fields of a collection.

Following are index fields:
{ 
    "field1" : "text", 
    "field2" : "text"
}

Below are the index options:
{ 
    "v" : 2, 
    "name" : "field1_text_field2_text", 
    "ns" : "db_name.collection_name", 
    "background" : true, 
    "weights" : {
        "field1" : 1, 
        "field2" : 1
    }, 
    "default_language" : "english", 
    "language_override" : "language", 
    "textIndexVersion" : 3
}

Comment: Amazon DocumentDB does not support text indexes. Does your workload require text indexes on the fields you specified? If you are looking to perform full text search queries over your data, we recommend you use Amazon Elasticsearch service (Amazon ES) along with Amazon DocumentDB. Amazon ES is purpose-built to enable you to run full text search queries over your data. Here is a blog that explains how to do so - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/run-full-text-search-queries-on-amazon-documentdb-data-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service/

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem when migrating to DocumentDB 4.0

As @meet-bhagdev said before, such indexes and index options DocumentDB does not support.

Please look at [DocumentDB Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html#mongo-apis-index), there you will find the root cause of our problem. And so far nothing can be done about it.

[image]